# How do I click a button on a website if it doesnt have an ID?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, automation, webbrowser-control

So im trying to automate a login to a website and the button im trying to click doesnt have a ID so I cant invoke a click to it.

This is what it looks like

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-green ng-binding">Login</button>
```

How do I click the button?

This is what I have so far.

```
private void btnFill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    wbBrowser.Document.GetElementById("login-username").InnerText = tbUsername.Text;
    wbBrowser.Document.GetElementById("login-password").InnerText = tbPassword.Text;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `runat="server"` and `onserverclick="btnFill_OnClick"` to your button? And why does it _have_ to be a HTML button?

Comment: Give it an ID manually or let ASP.NET assign one with a "runat" attrib.

Comment: Oh, im confused now haha :p 
What exactly do you mean? Can I give it an ID? Im jsut using a winform atm not ASP

Answer (score 2):

Use Xpath to locate element.

Something like this:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div/div/input"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign an ID to it.

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-green ng-binding" id="buttonSubmit">Login</button>
```

Comment: But its not my website, its a public website.

Comment: I am a bit confused. Do you not have access to the source code? I'm going to guess this is something like wordpress?

Comment: No it's a public website, Spotify to be specific. I'm using a webbrowser control to load it and then I get the document and access its controls and IDs from there.

Answer (score 0):

Find the class and the use

```
$(".ng-binding").click(function(){

});
```

, if there are multiple button with same class name , be more specific

```
$("#priviousDIV .ng-binding").click(function(){
    //do something
});
```

Comment: I'm using a winform application witha  webbrowser control, how do I find the class?

Comment: if you dont write runat="server" it just changes id value not class value. So you can find any class

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to study the DOM of the page and use that  knowledge to walk down the document tree programmatically. What you can do is find some parent element above the button that does have an ID and then walk down the tree till you find it.

```
    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var ParentElement = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("parentId");
        var child = ParentElement.Children[0];
        child.InvokeMember("click");
    }
```

Basically if you know the HTML structure of the page, you can find the element you are looking for.

Every modern web browser (Even IE) has some kind of built in tools which will let you inspect the HTML of page, use that and then craft your code to traverse it.